# Groovy Closures: How does the definition of Grails url mappings work

Tags: grails, reflection, groovy, closures

Please note that this question is not directly about url mappings in Grails. It is about how the way url mappings are defined.

When looking at `UrlMappings.groovy` we see something like this:

```
class UrlMappings {     
    static mappings = {         
        "/foo" (controller: "foo", action: "myaction")
        "/bar" (controller: "bar", action: "myaction")
        "404" (controller: 'error')
    }
}
```

The parentheses indicate that there is a function/method call. From my understanding the line

```
"/foo" (controller: "foo", action: "myaction")
```

executes the function named `/foo` of `UrlMappings`. If `UrlMappings` contains no function called `/foo` it will look at the closure delegate.

My problem is that the Strings you can use inside `mappings = { .. }` are not limited. You can add any kind of definition you want. For example:

```
"!%&/()" (controller: "foo")
```

So there has to be some kind of dynamic way of defining these functions. I couldn't think of a solution that defines these functions inside the `UrlMappings` class. So I tried to come up with a solution using the closure delegate.

With a simple groovy script I tried the following which worked fine for me:

```
def mappings = {
    "/foo" (controller: "foo", action: "myaction")
    "/bar" (controller: "bar", action: "myaction")
    "404" (controller: 'error')
    "!%&/()" (controller: "foo")
}

class MyMap extends LinkedHashMap {
    @Override
    public Object get(Object key) {
        if (!this.containsKey(key)) {
            this.put(key, { Map map -> println "$key called: $map" })
        }
        return super.get(key);
    }
}

mappings.delegate = new MyMap()
mappings()
```

So when `/foo` should be executed inside the `mappings` closure, groovy will look for a key named `/foo` in my delegate map. Therefore the `get()` method of `MyMap` is used. If no key with this name exists a new one will be created. The value of the key is always a closure that takes a map as parameter.

When executing the script I get:

```
/foo called: [controller:foo, action:myaction]
/bar called: [controller:bar, action:myaction]
404 called: [controller:error]
!%&/() called: [controller:foo]
```

So it worked. However I don't know if this is the way grails uses. Maybe there is a simpler solution?

So my first question is: **Is there another (maybe easier) way of doing this? / How does Grails resolve these function calls?**

Another question arised when I was experimenting with Maps as delegates.

Let's look at this:

```
def closure = {
    "foo" (arg: "foo")
}

closure.delegate = ["foo": { Map map -> println "called: $map" }]
closure() // error
```

I expected that this piece of code should print the string `called: [arg:foo]`. However I get:

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Test.foo() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[arg:foo]]

Then I tried the following which results (as expected) in the same exception:

```
def delegate = new LinkedHashMap()
delegate["foo"] = { Map map -> println "called: $map" }
closure.delegate = delegate 
closure() // error
```

However if I do:

```
class MyLinkedHashMap extends LinkedHashMap { }
def delegate = new MyLinkedHashMap()
delegate["foo"] = { Map map -> println "called: $map" }
closure.delegate = delegate 
closure() // prints "called: [arg:foo]"
```

It works.

So my second question is: **Why does this not work with a simple `LinkedHashMap` but works with `MyLinkedHashMap` (which does not modify anything) ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you read about methodMissing?

an example is here: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Using+methodMissing+and+propertyMissing

another here: http://blog.vladimirvivien.com/2008/02/25/creating-a-simple-builder-with-groovys-methodmissing/

grails does it by passing this list of closures to [this builder](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-plugin-url-mappings/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/mapping/DefaultUrlMappingEvaluator.java#L209) which overrides invokeMethod to do the work, [as explained here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Using+invokeMethod+and+getProperty)

Comment: +1 thanks for the links. I didn't know this. I will leave the question open for now because I hope someone can give me the answer to my 2nd question.

Comment: The second answer may be hard to come by.  it seems like it may have to do with the fact that your new class is going to be a GroovyObject, while built-in java objects won't be.  If you looks at groovy source, Closure.java's `getPropertyTryThese()` will be called to resolve `"foo"`, which will call InvokerHelper's `getProperty()` method, which routes the call differently based on the GroovyObject-ness of the object.  Beyond that lies the rest of a rabbit hole, I'd say...  You can also replace usage of your class with `def delegate = new Expando()`.